# Am a spouse of an eea family member living in the uk

Tags: visa, resident-permit, family, dependent-visa

Am a spouse of an eea family member living in the uk, i have a 5 years family permit. but now i have my own EEA passport(French). what do i do. after 5 years or within the 5 years can i apply for permanent on my own?

Answer (score 1):

> After 5 years or within the 5 years can I apply for permanent on my own?

You ought to be a permanent resident after five years of residence, even if you changed from being a non-EEA family member to being an EU citizen in your own right.

You should be aware that as a French citizen you have no need for a [residence card](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card) or for an [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit).  You will probably want to be certain when you apply for the [EU settlement scheme](https://www.gov.uk/settled-status-eu-citizens-families) that your status as a French citizen is clear.